# Draw A Curved Line On An Image

Tags: python, image, opencv, draw

I have an image with some points, and I need to draw the line of best fit on the image. The points would make a polynomial line.

This is what I've got so far:

```
#The coordinates are filled in earlier (self.lx, self.ly)
z = np.polyfit(self.lx, self.ly, 2)
lspace = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
draw_x = lspace
draw_y = np.polyval(z, draw_x)   #I am unsure of how to draw it on to the image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a polyline on an image you can use polylines of opencv:

Drawing Polygon

To draw a polygon, first you need coordinates of vertices. Make those points into an array of shape ROWSx1x2 where ROWS are number of vertices and it should be of type int32. Here we draw a small polygon of with four vertices in yellow color.

pts = np.array([[10,5],[20,30],[70,20],[50,10]], np.int32)

pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))

cv.polylines(img,[pts],True,(0,255,255))

Note
If third argument is False, you will get a polylines joining all the points, not a closed shape.
cv.polylines() can be used to draw multiple lines. Just create a list of all the lines you want to draw and pass it to the function. All lines will be drawn individually. It is a much better and faster way to draw a group of lines than calling cv.line() for each line.